# Hello, I need help on creating a Star Wars name generator using specific instructions

Tags: java, parameters, java.util.scanner, trim

I'm struggling with a specific method which takes in a `String` parameter. The `promptString` method will print its parameter to the user as a prompt, and then return a `String` that is the result of reading the console via the `nextLine()` method. For this program you will use `nextLine()` exclusively.

I've prompted  the user with a question using a parameter, and then used `nextLine` to read the string but after that I am a bit lost. How can I get the method to print to the console?

```
import java.util.*;
public class StarWarsName{
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    promptString("Enter your first name: ");
  }
  public static String promptString (String n) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String first = console.nextline();
    return first.trim();
  }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.print(n);`

Comment: are you looking for `System.out.println("Any string");`? That is right from HelloWorld example

Comment: Print the call. Also, you never prompt (print the prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-thinking this thing. Just print it to the console.

```
 public static void main(String[]args){
  String result = promptString("Enter your first name: "); 
  System.out.println(result); 
 }
```